# Zeebe cancel deployed instances

Tags: scala, zeebe

Recently I have tried using zeebe, zeebe io on scala, and I have some unfinished instances, and donno how to remove them, can anyone suggest me any desicion about that?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Workflow instances can be canceled via:

Comand line:

```
zbctl cancel instance INSTANCE_KEY
```

Programmatically via Client (java api example):

```
zeebeClient
   .newCancelInstanceCommand(instanceKey)
    .send();
```

or directly in operate with the cancel button at the right of each line.

Comment: cancel button on camunda didn't work, i will try first command, thanks